# D3 animate Leaflet polyline

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am trying to animmate Polyline using D3.
But it didn't work. Here is what I tried:

```
    function drawPolyline(x1,y1,x2,y2, tooltip)
    {
        var arr = [];
        arr.push(map.unproject([x1 , y1]));
        arr.push(map.unproject([x2 , y2]));
        var options ={color: 'green', weight: 3,opacity: 0.5, smoothFactor: 1 };
        var polyline = new L.Polyline(arr, options);
        polyline.addTo(map);
        var label =  new L.Label({offset: [-20, -20]});
        label.setContent(tooltip);
        label.setLatLng(polyline.getBounds().getCenter());
        map.showLabel(label);
        d3.select(polyline).transition()
    .duration(350)
    .attr({stroke: "rgb(0, 41, 255)" , fill: "rgb(0, 41, 255)"})
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using d3.select on the `L.Polyline` instance, that won't work. It's not a SVG path element. The actual path element is stored in your `L.Polyline` instance as member property `_path`. Try this:

```
d3.select(polyline._path).transition().duration(350).attr('stroke', 'rgb(0, 41, 255)')
```